# Install FTP on IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, ftp

How does one install FTP publishing in IIS 7?

Adding the Role service doesn't work.

With a previous Win 2008 server I had to download FTP 7.5 as a seperate install for IIS 7.  I did that this time but again to no avail.

Is there a standard way to install the Role Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two versions of IIS FTP you can install on Windows 2008 Server:

> IIS FTP 6.0
>   IIS FTP 7.5

IIS FTP 6.0 looks and feels just like IIS FTP running on IIS 6.0. This is useful for legacy applications that still rely on ADSI code to create FTP sites the 'old way'. You can install this by adding the FTP Publishing Service in the Server Roles wizard.

IIS FTP 7.5 is a ground up re-write of FTP for Windows 2008. It's not currently included as a Role Service or Feature out of the box on Windows 2008 but can be downloaded separately from:

> http://www.iis.net/extensions/ftp

IIS FTP 7.5 supports now supports many good things such as FTP over SSL and Virtual FTP Hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

What happened when you tried to add the role service?  That is the [official](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732769%28WS.10%29.aspx) way to install FTP, and has worked for me in the past in windows 2008.

Comment: it forces me to launch ftp via iis6 console, which would require me to redo all the config of sites i'm porting...initially, I installed the new version of ftp7.5 for iis 7 as a stand alone, but that's not working this time.  for some reason, ftp related controls aren't appearing.   i'll reboot and see what happens.

Comment: Ah, in that case what I considered to be a working FTP site is what is no good for you :-)